# Why is my while loop not terminating after the condition that is set true?

Tags: python

This is all of the code in my while loop. I have declared the num outside the def statement jest so I don't get a global variable error.

Do you need to call all of the other def statements back to the loop?

```
num = 0;
def Loop(NumOfFeedback, num):
    while num < NumOfFeedback:
        classOne(Math,Science,English,History,Band,Choir,Spanish,French,German)
        workloadOne(Little,Medium,aLot)
        classTwo(MathA,ScienceA,EnglishA,HistoryA,BandA,ChoirA,SpanishA,FrenchA,GermanA)
        workloadTwo(LittleA,MediumA,aLotA)
        GPA(FourPO,ThreePFive,ThreePO,TwoPFive,TwoPO)
        Age(A14,B15,C16,D17,E18)
        num = num + 1
        print num
```

Comment: While it's good to keep the code you post short, doing so by posting an unrunnable fragment of a larger body of code means we usually don't have the context necessary to tell what's going wrong. Instead, take your program and simplify it, tearing out anything that doesn't make the bug go away or render the program unrunnable when you remove it. Replacing user input with hardcoded values, removing loops unrelated to the problem, and similar techniques can help isolate the source of the bug.

Comment: Structurally I can't see anything wrong. Can I suggest that you keep track of both `num` and `NumOfFeedback` while debugging.

Comment: It's difficult to tell from your question, but are you expecting your while loop to terminate as soon as the condition becomes false?  It will not - the condition is only evaluated at the start of the loop.

Comment: One thing that comes to mind is: `5 < '4'`; If you were using Python 3 you'd get `TypeError: unorderable types: int() < str()`. Additionally, if you're new to python, why wouldn't you want to use Python 3 (command `python3` on many OS, or) instead of soon-to-be-EOLed Python 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only defining Loop but you are probably not running it.
When you def a function you just save it, but in order to run it you have to call it from your code.
add this at the end of your code (with the values you need):

```
Loop([NumOfFeedback], num)
```

You should change the name of the function to be lowercased (and other than just loop - super not clear).
Also move `num = 0` down - right above the call.